# How to create a movable and clickable button in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin Android and currently working on a floating action button, I implemented **View.IOnTouchListener** and normal button click event (faButton.Click += floatButtonPressed;) to carry out my actions. But for the **case MotionEventActions.Move**, it doesn't work as I wanted. Moving left and right it works fine but for top and bottom it will move downwards a little bit whenever I start moving it. Besides, when I move the button to screen border it will be able to exceed the screen. Hence, I tried detect screen size and restrict it but it still not good enough, is there any other available solution or settings?

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                oldXvalue = e.GetX();
                oldYvalue = e.GetY();

                if (oldXvalue == e.GetX() && oldYvalue == e.GetY())
                {
                    return false;
                }

                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Up:

                if (oldXvalue == e.GetX() && oldYvalue == e.GetY())
                {
                    return false;
                }                   
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                var xleft = (int)(e.RawX - oldXvalue);
                var xright = xleft + v.Width;
                var ytop = (int)(e.RawY - oldYvalue);
                var ybtm = (ytop + v.Height);
                if (xleft + v.Width >= intWidth)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (xleft <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (ytop + v.Height >= intHeight)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (ytop <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                v.Layout(xleft, ytop, xright, ybtm);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you can dois remove and add view (Button) on touch

Comment: What do you meant by remove and add view? Can you give me some hints? @JinalPatel

Comment: you want movable button fro that you can use one button which will added where you touch and removed from last position

Comment: I get what you mean now. This is also a solution but I wish the button can be like user touch on it and drag to position instead of adding and removing. Thank you so much for your answer sir. @JinalPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the screen height and screen width first. And when the button exceed the screen you need to reset the button position.

Try the following code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnTouchListener
    {
        Button dragAbleBt;
        int screenWidth = 0;
        int screenHeight = 0;
        int lastX = 0, lastY = 0;
        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {            
            MotionEventActions ea = e.Action;
            switch (ea) {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    lastX = (int)e.RawX;
                    lastY = (int)e.RawY;                
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    int dx = (int)e.RawX - lastX;
                    int dy = (int)e.RawY - lastY;
                    int left = v.Left + dx;
                    int right = v.Right + dx;
                    int top = v.Top + dy;
                    int bottom = v.Bottom + dy;
                    if (left < 0)
                    {
                        left = 0;
                        right = left + v.Width;
                    }
                    if (right > screenWidth)
                    {
                        right = screenWidth;
                        left = right - v.Width;
                    }
                    if (top < 0)
                    {
                        top = 0;
                        bottom = top + v.Height;
                    }
                    if (bottom > screenHeight)
                    {
                        bottom = screenHeight;
                        top = bottom - v.Height;
                    }
                    v.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
                    lastX = (int) e.RawX;
                    lastY = (int) e.RawY;
                    v.PostInvalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:                  
                    break;                   
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            //DisplayMetrics dm = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
            //screenWidth = dm.WidthPixels;
            //screenHeight = dm.HeightPixels;
            dragAbleBt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            dragAbleBt.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
        {
            base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                Rect outRect = new Rect();
                this.Window.FindViewById(Window.IdAndroidContent).GetDrawingRect(outRect);
                screenWidth = outRect.Width();
                screenHeight = outRect.Height();
            }
        }
    }
```

> I tried detect screen size and restrict it but it still not good enough, is there any other available solution or settings?

You may got the whole screen width and height, the button will exceed the screen height, In this kind of situation you need get the view drawing area by `this.Window.FindViewById(Window.IdAndroidContent).GetDrawingRect(outRect)`

Screen Shot:

Note: I am using the emulator that is slow, If you are using the real device it will be faster.

[image]

Comment: This codes work perfectly. It solved both of my questions. Thank you so much bro! @MikeMa